# can't post answer on community blocked question, have enough points

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, reputation, protected-posts

This is more of a bug report:

[No option to hibernate/shutdown in GNOME 3?](https://superuser.com/questions/267303/no-option-to-hibernate-shutdown-in-gnome-3?123)

text under the message says:

> protected by Community♦ Oct 22 at 14:12
>
> This question is protected to prevent "thanks!", "me too!", or spam
>   answers by new users. To answer it, you must have earned more than 10
>   reputation on this site.

I currently have 32, which is >10. I can even edit the accepted response (that does not answer the full question) if so I wished.

So why can't I add another answer?

[image]

Comment: Are you sure you can't answer it? Does it give you an error message when you try to answer, or is there just no answer textbox?

Comment: there's no answer or comment buttons. but i have the edit showing up on other people's post and even the question. I mean, answer input box

Comment: A screenshot would be useful here :)

Comment: added screen shot

Comment: Try logging out and in again, also try to force a cache refresh on that page using CTRL+F5. Verify that you are logged in, [the permissions page](http://superuser.com/privileges) says `100%` for the entry and you have received a message at the top that said you gained the privilege.

Comment: @TomWijsman The user has a 150 rep bounty [here](http://superuser.com/questions/268512/mount-encrypted-safe-boot-windows-partition-under-linux) (ending in 10 minutes). He's been on the site for a while and much more active than 32 rep.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the "can answer a protected question" check, the account association bonus of 100 rep is deduced from your reputation, hence the *on this site* part of the message. Granted, you're somewhat of an edge case here (because of your bounty), but a user who has *not* received the association bonus and spent all their rep on bounties cannot answer a preotected question either.

Comment: Just to clarify, 101 rep users coming from a different site see the same message? This should probably be documented better, especially since high-rep users can protect questions. // I'm not sure it makes sense protecting questions when the same users can post comments and vote...

Comment: still not clear... i had 182, -150 bounty =  32, -100 non-site-rep (just learned about it and the link to the FAQ in the message doesn't even mention it) = -68 ...is that my site-reputation?

Comment: @gcb: As far as that check is concerned, yes.

Comment: @DanielBeck i can't post comments. just vote and Edit the questions and answers already there, which is even odder :) also of note, there was no +1 or mee too comment/answer on that blocked question :(

Comment: @balpha that's very cryptic, but settles it.

Comment: @gcb: I meant, the idea of "site reputation" doesn't exist anywhere outside the "protected question" check (at least I can't think of anything), but for the purpose of that check, the value that was compared to the "at least 10" requirement was indeed -68. Also, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/109117/can-the-protect-feature-be-made-to-block-101-users-as-well as an example of why this happens.